# append to existing parent theme function

Tags: functions, filters, navigation, parent-theme

My parent theme calls a function:

```
function get_nav_markup() {
    ob_start();
?>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse site-navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <?php if ( is_home() ): ?>
            <h1 class="navbar-brand mb-0">
                <?php echo get_sitename_formatted(); ?>
            </h1>
            <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?php echo bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>" class="navbar-brand">
                <?php echo get_sitename_formatted(); ?>
            </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header-menu" aria-controls="header-menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
                    'depth'           => 2,
                    'container'       => 'div',
                    'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id'    => 'header-menu',
                    'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav ml-md-auto',
                ) );
            ?>
        </div>
    </nav>
<?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

and then later uses it like so:

```
function get_header_markup() {
    global $post;
    echo get_nav_markup( $post );

    $videos = get_header_videos( $post );
    $images = get_header_images( $post );

    if ( $videos || $images ) {
        echo get_header_media_markup( $post, $videos, $images );
    }
    else {
        echo get_header_default_markup( $post );
    }
}
```

Is there anyway that I can overwrite get_nav_markup or at least append additional information immediately after it in my child theme?

Given the way the parent theme function written I don't think I can. But I really need to be able to add some additional DIVs and PHP right after the /nav

Comment: If the theme author had set an `action` there, you could. How it looks right now I'm not sure if there is any way possible

Comment: If your parent theme's function wrapped in a conditional like `if ( !function_exists('get_nav_markup') ) {}` then you can copy the whole function in child theme's functions.php file. A child theme is loaded before the parent theme, so if you define a function in child theme WordPress will execute that first.

Comment: Yeah I understand that IF the function had been written differently, I might have other options. But that's not the case here. So I need to deal with the cards I've been dealt here.

Comment: A dirty alternative would be using jQuery to insert content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is what I have decided given the situation.

1. I have copied the header.php file into my child theme.
2. I have changed the line in the header file from get_header_markup(); to get_header_markup_updated();
3. I have then created a new function in my child themes function.php file called get_header_markup_updated.
4. I started the function off my copying the existing one from the parent theme, but then added the code I needed... where I needed it.

The result now looks like:

```
function get_header_markup_updated() {
    global $post;
    echo get_nav_markup( $post ); ?>
<div class="breadcrumbnav">
    <!-- Inserted all my other code here --> 
</div>
<?php       
    $videos = get_header_videos( $post );
    $images = get_header_images( $post );

    if ( $videos || $images ) {
        echo get_header_media_markup( $post, $videos, $images );
    }
    else {
        echo get_header_default_markup( $post );
    }
}
?>
```

This seems to be working just fine. Hopefully this will also be the least obtrusive going forward.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't appear to be possible. At least not directly. You can replace functions in parent themes if they are wrapped in:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'get_nav_markup' ) ) {
}
```

Because child themes are loaded before the parent this gives you an opportunity to define `get_nav_markup()` before the parent theme is loaded. That `if` statement means that the parent function won't register the function if you already have in the child theme.

If the parent theme had hooked the function with `add_action()`, like this:

```
add_action( 'hook_name', 'get_nav_markup' );
```

Then you could have replaced the function by writing your own and hooking it in place of the original function:

```
remove_action( 'hook_name', 'get_nav_markup' );
add_action( 'hook_name', 'my_get_nav_markup' );
```

So since the parent theme does not do either of these, your only option is to make the replacement at the template level. You will need to:

1. Copy the `get_nav_markup()` function to your child theme, but rename it. Then make whatever change you want to make to it.
2. Copy the `get_header_markup()` function to your child theme, rename it, and replace the reference to `get_nav_markup()` to the renamed and modified copy in your child theme.
3. Find whichever template uses `get_header_markup()`, presumably header.php, copy it to your child theme, so that it replaces the parent theme's, and change the reference to `get_header_markup()` to your renamed and modified version.

Answer (score 1):

if *get_header_markup()* is used in a template page you can easily overwrite the template of the parent theme with a file named in the same way ( suppose the template file is *theme/template1.php* create a file named *child-theme/template1.php* in your child theme folder) and call a new custom function from there.

```
echo NEW_get_nav_markup( $post );
```

otherwise, you need to check if the *get_header_markup()* has been called via *add_action()* somewhere, in this case you can remove and add a new one

```
remove_action('called hook','get_header_markup', 10, 2);
add_action('called hook','NEW_get_header_markup', 10, 2);
```

if this is the case remember that to remove an action prevoiously added via add_action() you have to use same priority and arguments.

In my experience, being a theme-based architecture (not plugin) it's almost always possible, starting from the template file that outputs contents, to find, way back, a point where overwrite the original functions using template files of the child theme.